# Restrict Azure Logic App custom connector HTTP headers

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm using a custom connector to connect to an on prem SOAP web service via a data gateway. The request is failing due to the large number of x-ms-* HTTP headers being added by the custom connector. The target web service is hosted on Apache Tomcat and has a restriction on HTTP header total size (which I cannot control). Is there any way in either logic app or custom connector configuration to stop these HTTP headers being added?

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately, there is no way to control this from logic apps itself**. Instead, you could front your SOAP service with a proxy that handles this for you.

In the cloud, you could use Azure APIM which can **strip headers from being forwarded to your SOAP service**.

You can also [deploy APIM in a VNET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet) for it to access sources on-premises via a VPN Gateway or an Express Route connection.